# How to make element scrolled to bottom in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, scroll

In my app I want to make my element always scrolled to bottom after getting new logs.
For some reason my `logsRef.current.scrollTop` has value of zero all the time. My logs do show on screen and in console. I am not sure why is this not working, I've tried to use different approaches using `useLyaoutEffect()` but nothing made `logsRef.current.scrollTop` value change, it stayed zero all the time.

```
//my Logs.jsx component
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Container from "./UI/Container";
import styles from "./Logs.module.css";

const Logs = ({ logs }) => {
  const logsRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    logsRef.current.scrollTop = logsRef.current.scrollHeight;
    console.log(logs);
    console.log(logsRef.current.scrollTop);
  }, [logs]);

  return (
    <Container className={`${styles.logs} ${styles.container}`}>
      <div ref={logsRef}>
        {" "}
        {logs.map((log, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{log}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
export default Logs;
```

Also, I do render my Logs.jsx in BattlePhase.jsx component where I do my *attack* logic on click and I save logs using useState() hook.

```
//parts where i do save my logs in BattlePhase.jsx

const [logs, setLogs] = useState([]);

const attackHandler = () => {
//logs where pokemon on left attacked pokemon on right
setLogs((prevLogs) => [
              ...prevLogs,
              `${pokemonDataOne.name} attacked ${
                pokemonDataTwo.name
              } for ${attack.toFixed(2)} dmg`,
              `${pokemonDataTwo.name} died`,
            ])
}
...
 <Attack className={isActiveArrow}>
          <Button onClick={attackHandler}>Attack!</Button>
        </Attack>
```

[image: My logs on render and in console.]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There should be enough code to exactly reproduce the error when run.

Comment: Thank you for commenting @Unmitigated. This is minimal as it gets, you may copy hooks and <div> element that has map function which returns logs to make  reproducible example (reprex). My compiler doesn't shows syntax error but it just doesn't work as it is supposed to.

Comment: It does not reproduce the issue as you do not show where you are changing the logs.

Comment: I hope I've provided parts where I do change the logs. @Unmitigated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight long shot but it's possible that the ref is attached to the wrong element. Are you sure the element with the CSS property that makes it scrollable (`overflow`) isn't on `<Container>`?

```
//my Logs.jsx component
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Container from "./UI/Container";
import styles from "./Logs.module.css";

const Logs = ({ logs }) => {
  const logsRef = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    logsRef.current.scrollTop = logsRef.current.scrollHeight;
    console.log(logs);
    console.log(logsRef.current.scrollTop);
  }, [logs]);

  return (
    <Container className={`${styles.logs} ${styles.container}`} ref={logsRef}>
      <div>
        {" "}
        {logs.map((log, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{log}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
export default Logs;
```

Also to confirm, you do need `useLayoutEffect` here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I was not aware I need to specify ```overflow-y: scroll;``` to element in order to manipulate scroll. I was thinking ```logsRef.current.scrollTop = logsRef.current.scrollHeight;```   will affect scrolling behaviour alone. It works now! Also it works fine without ```useLayoutEffect()```.

Comment: You might have bugs in future if you don't `useLayoutEffect` here. In fact I think you will have one now. When `logs` updates, and the page is long enough to cause the scroll to kick in, it will actually use the `scrollHeight` of the container *before* that new log was added. This would cause a small offset issue. Probably as well when the component mounts you'll have errors in console since with `useEffect` on first mount you'd be referencing a DOM element that does not exist.